# Spring Database Load Test: How to release connections

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat

I was just trying to simplify my Problem in a little Show-Case-Application.
It seems like the Connection doesn't get closed until the Thread finished. [**Check this out**](https://github.com/bastiankemmer/Spring-Hibernate-Problem)

**Dependencies Information:**

**Servlet Engine**: Apache Tomcat/8.5.5
**JPA Provider:** Hibernate

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>***-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>...</name>
    <description>...</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.cloud.release.version>Brixton.SR2</spring.cloud.release.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- eureka discovery client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for unit tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for rest documentation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for (un)marshalling of json / xml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ http://jsoup.org/ -->
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- also needed for eureka discovery -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.cloud.release.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                    <outputDirectory>${dir}</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have a Spring Boot Server with MYSQL as DB. When I am Load-Testing (JMeter) with more than 100 Threads/Users, I get this Exception:

> org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [http-nio-8015-exec-195] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 60 seconds, none available[size:50; busy:50; idle:0; lastwait:60000].

My Datasource Configuration:

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.minIdle = 0
spring.datasource.tomcat.maxIdle = 10
spring.datasource.tomcat.maxActive = 50
spring.datasource.tomcat.maxWait = 60000
spring.datasource.tomcat.testOnBorrow = true
spring.datasource.tomcat.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 1800000 // Updated
spring.datasource.tomcat.numTestsPerEvictionRun = 50  // Updated
spring.datasource.tomcat.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 10
spring.datasource.tomcat.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.datasource.tomcat.testWhileIdle = true
```

The only query on the Database is a simple `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE deletedat IS NULL`. It returns about 4000 Entries in about 0.01 seconds (via mysql CLI).
I have installed Neor Profile SQL to Profile my MYSQL DB. When I check all processes, the processes on my Schema are all Sleeping. It seems like my Configuration doesn't release those Connections.

I am using a simple Interface which extends from CrudRepository:

```
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyModel, String> {
    @Query("SELECT m from MyModel m WHERE m.deletedAt IS NULL")
    List<MyModel> findWhereDeletedAtIsNull();
}
```

and use it

```
List<MyModel> myModelList = myRepository.findWhereDeletedAtIsNull();
```

What am I missing?
It seems that either the Configuration or the Code needs to be adapted in order to release connections.

**Hibernate Config:**

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: The values you've set for timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis and minEvictableIdleTimeMillis are too low, that's milliseconds... The Tomcat docs say "value should not be set under 1 second", ie 1000 and even that seems too often to be running validation queries... See if adjusting those values helps...

Comment: may be you can add the dependencies information like tomcat and boot version to the post and also you can increase logging for spring boot to see if find anything in the logs

Comment: Where are the connection pool parameters?

Comment: and what about your JPA provider configuration?

Comment: @B.Kemmer  yes, that's almost evident. but what is your configuration for hibernate? and how you are bootstrapping the hibernate inside of your application.   and a little bit more code, regarding web method you are trying to call would be nice, and just have a look at tomcat threads, where are those: it seems that they just stalled somewhere in between...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your jpa configuration registering the `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` which binds a JPA EntityManager to the worker thread for the entire processing of the request. Hence database connection are getting closed(or returned to pool) after finishing of service method (com.example.api.UserService.getAllUser()).

This keeps your DB connection open for longer time and your connection pool is getting exhausted during load.

To fix your issue you can disable the auto registration of `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` filter by adding [below property](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) in your application.properties

> spring.jpa.open-in-view=false

This property is true by default.

See related issues:
 1. [Consider not registering `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` by default](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7107)

Comment: gotta try this, but it seems to be the problem. i will accept your answer after i made sure it works now

Answer (score 1):

What is critical, here, is to enable `logAbandoned`. That way, Tomcat's JDBC pool will tell you *where* the connections are being allocated that aren't being returned. As of now, you are merely trying to *recover* from the problem by covering it up: forcing the pool to release connections that haven't been properly-returned.

The `java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed` is happening because you have a query that is taking longer than 50 seconds to complete, but it is being properly cleaned-up by your own code. So after 50 seconds, the pool closes the connection (because it's been "abandoned") and then when your code gets control back, it also closes the connection. Consider raising your abandoned-connection timeout.

Comment: That literally summarizes the problem pretty good. I have just added a showcase project. It seems like the connection doesn't get released until the thread finished. Even if i don't use the connection anymore. How can i close the connection manually and is it good practice to do so?

Comment: Sorry... Hibernate isn't my jam. I write my JDBC by hand, just as god intended. Does the `@Transactional` annotation expand the scope of the connection-use? Perhaps that annotation means that any queries executed during that request should be grouped together in a single transaction, which necessarily means that the connection must be exclusive to that request.. until it completes, I guess. You may want to consider hand-writing some of that JDBC code. It's more work, but it will be more efficient and do exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: https://github.com/bastiankemmer/Spring-Hibernate-Problem
Check this Project. 
`@Transactional` does define the scope of a single db transaction, but isn't part of my problem.